# Play default soft keyboard sound when buttons are pressed in android

Tags: android

I have developed an app which uses my own `custom keyboard` (well, a view that looks like a keyboard and behaves like a keyboard anyway). One thing I've yet to figure it out is how to make it play the `default soft keyboard 'click'` sound when the buttons are pressed. 
Is there any easy way to do this?

I would like to use the `keyboard click` sound that comes with the phone rather than providing my own. As different phones might have different keyboard click sounds, I would like to keep my application consistent. Ultimately, I want to reflect the same settings the user has chosen in their *global* keyboard settings (play/not play sounds, vibrate/not vibrate, etc).

Comment: Note that lots of phones don’t even use the stock keyboard by default.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have found a solution to this. All I needed to do was implement a `OnTouchListener` on the button and use the `AudioManager.playSoundEffect()` public method. Code is shown below:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
float vol = 0.5; //This will be half of the default system sound
am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEY_CLICK, vol);
```

Comment: I get `AUDIO_SERVICE cannot be resolved to a variable` (JB 4.1.2)

Comment: @LuisA.Florit: try: Context.AUDIO_SERVICE. Works well

Comment: The volume of 0.5 is default? Is there a way to get this from the system as well?

Comment: How to get sound same as user dial keypad?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (isSetVibration) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(50, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
        } else {
            ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(50);
        }
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(0, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
        } else {
            ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(0);
        }
    }
```